# Regarding amortized analyis

Tags: algorithm

This is regarding amortized analysis. Following is text from an article.

> Amortized analyis for problems in which one must perform a series of
>   operations, and our goal is to analyze the time per operation. The
>   motivation for amortized analysis is that looking at the worst case
>   time per operation can be too pessimistic if the only way to produce
>   an expensive is to "set it up" with a a large number of cheap
>   operations before hand.

Question: What does author mean by last statement i.e., "if the only way to produce an expensive is to "set it up" with a a large number of cheap operations before
hand"? Can any one please explain with example what this statement mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example. Consider an array that dynamically increases it's capacity when an element is added that exceeds the current capacity. Let increasing the capacity be O(n), where n is the old size of the array. Now, adding an element has a worst case complexity of O(n), because we might have to increase the capacity. The idea behind amortized analysis is that you have to do n simple adds that cost O(1) before the capacity is exhausted. Thus, many cheap operations lead up to one expensive operation. In other words, the expensive operation is amortized by the cheap operations.

Comment: Just to add some concrete details: Inserts, in general, take O(1). The insert that causes the array to increase capacity is O(n). Since it takes n inserts to get there the amortized costs is O(n)/n = O(1).

Answer (score 1):

The author means that the only way an expensive operation can occour is to be preceded by a big number of cheap operations.

Look at this example:
We have a stack and we want the stack to implement in addition to the usual operations, also a operation called multipop(k) that pop k elements. Now, multipop costs O(min(n, k)), where n is the size of the stack; thus the prerequisite for the multipop to costs for example O(k) is to be precided by at least k cheap push each costing O(1).

Comment: The key idea here is that a sequence of m multipops would normally have a complexity of O(k*m) (because a single multi-pop has O(k)). Amortized analysis shows us that multipop is in fact O(1), because you cannot pop more elements than are on the stack.

Comment: @Bjorn Pollex but how do we get multipop as O(1)

Comment: because to cost O(k) a multipop must be preceded by at least k O(1) push; then the total cost for k+1 operations would be k * O(1) + O(k) = O(k) and then for 1 operation: O(k) / k = O(1)